# Php/Python : executing python from php?

Tags: php, python, shell, exec, passthru

```
passthru('python directory_read.py < 5');    
passthru('python directory_read.py < 1');
```

the first line of code works perfectly fine while the second line does'nt works?
also directory_read.py reads the contents of a directory upto 5 or 1 depth
i have tried exec and system commands.

Comment: What isn't working? And have you tried subprocess?

Comment: no idea why this is'nt working

Comment: What's your luck with subprocess?

Comment: ok, i did'nt try subprocess rather i tried something different. its called getopt(in python) to get arguments from command line.
i also checked the subprocess documentation, i guess that's not exactly what i want. althogh it'll do the task.

Comment: Have you tried `passthru('python directory_read.py < 4');` or `3` or `2` chained together, or running `1` by itself?

Comment: yes i tried that, no luck, it did'nt work.

Comment: So the only thing that doesn't work is chaining two passthru's together?